# Laptop no longer recognizing usb-c connected monitor as a display through two operating systems

Tags: display

I have a Lenovo Yoga 920.  I have a dual-boot setup with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 22.04.  I have two different USB-C / HDMI setups (one docking station, one more of just-a-converter).

Today when I plugged in the laptop to the docking station, it did not recognize the display.  It recognized it was connected to the docking stationn - I heard the audio of a connection - but there was no display connected.

I tried many different iterations....

```
Lenovo / Ubuntu + Docking Station + HDMI Cable A = no display
Lenovo / Ubuntu + Converter Cable + HDMI Cable A = no display
Lenovo / Windows + Docking Station + HDMI Cable A = no display
Lenovo / Windows + Converter Cable + HDMI Cable A = no display
Lenovo / Ubuntu + Converter Cable + HDMI Cable B = no display

Alternate Laptop (Dell) / Windows + Docking Station + HDMI Cable A = display works
```

So the common thread thus far is that the Lenovo does not recognize an external display.

Any thoughts?  This seems to be some sort of hardware issue, and yet I can't find a setting in the BIOS or elsewhere that indicates where the issue may lie.

Comment: Does everything else work via the USB-C port?  Via the docking station?  Please update your question to include the complete model of 920 as well as the docking station and the "converter cable"

Comment: Did the monitor work via the USB-C cable previously? This is implied, but not actually stated, ans we need to know this.